# Positioning img with different size/ratio and filling it in in div

Tags: jquery, html, css, position, image

I have a website that users upload images to, the image processing is made on the server and the size is 400px*400px. The images may come in vary of original sizes on which there is no control. when displaying them I cannot position them correctly in a 200px*200px div. its either squeezed/stretched or leaves a letterbox like space. The preference here is to crop the images at the cost of keeping the right ratio and centering them. any jquery/css known methods to do so?

**Edit**

```
.container{width:200px; height:200px;}
.container img{width:100%;}
```

That was the closest solution Ive found however its not satisfying at all (height/width obviously changes according to the pics)... currently we use a letterbox to 'scale' the images.
There's also Pixel Daily's photo stack plugin which is used [PhotoStack](http://pixelsdaily.com/resources/html-css/css-image-stacks/)

Comment: My bad.. thanks, added some more information regarding the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

give image height and width 100%

try

```
.imgClass{  //your class name
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: this does not crop the images nor does it keep the aspect ratio within the div

Answer (score 0):

For modern browsers (no IE8 or lower) you could achieve this with css only using the [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) property "cover" in conjunction with the background property inline.

```
 <ul>
    <li style="background:url('image/path.jpg') center center;background-size:cover"></li>
    <li style="background:url('image/path.jpg') center center;background-size:cover"></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EXpb2/1/

Comment: since I use a css plugin to create a photo stack like effect I cannot change the background image, the positioning, I guess, should somehow be done dynamically.